# Why is DATE_FORMAT() in php a few hours behind?

Tags: php, date, date-format

The form I am using to submit data to the database is processing the time incorrectly (usually a few hours behind the actual time). The output below was really done at 9:28 not 7:28. How do I fix this so that it processes the time correctly? I do not want to use military time. Is it possible that it could be something with my website hosting service? I tried this on XAMPP and everything works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
DATE_FORMAT(posts.post_date, '%W, %M %e, %Y at %h:%i %p') AS date
```

Output:

```
Saturday, July 6, 2013 at 07:28 PM
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your default timezone with [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)?

Comment: No. How would I go about doing that? Do I have to do that on my hosting service somewhere?

Comment: I added an answer below, as others have also done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time would go by your server time. An easy workaround for this is to manually set the timezone before the date() or time() functions are called to.

I'm in Kolkata, India so I have something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Or another example is LA - US:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

You can also see what timezone the server is currently in via:

```
date_default_timezone_get();
```

So something like:

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone;
```

So the short answer for your question would be:

```
// Change the line below to your timezone!
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

Then all the times would be to the timezone you just set :)

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea about this whole thing. Your answer really helped me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, you can set the default timezone for your dates and times using
`date_default_timezone_set()`.  The documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

The list of supported timezones can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).  You can pass your default timezone as a parameter in the aforementioned method.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn E_NOTICE on, you'd probably work this one out as it chucks up notices if you use date/time functions without setting the time zone.

> bool date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )

E.G:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: How do I turn E_NOTICE on? When I put in the boolean statement into my code I get an error.